# how can I filter an array within a list by searching in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I would like some idea to make a filter in one list searching in another list

how can I filter an array within a list by searching in another array?

like this...

````
    myArray = [
      {
        "name": "Item-A", "tags":
          ["Facebook", "Google"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Item-B", "tags":
          ["Facebook", "Google", "Apple"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Item-C", "tags":
          ["Apple"]
      },
    ];

    //array for filter
    paramsFilter = ["Facebook", "Apple"];

    //result espected
    [
      {
        "name": "Item-B", "tags":
          ["Facebook", "Google", "Apple"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Item-C", "tags":
          ["Apple"]
      },
    ]```


I am doing a filter by tags so that it will check "paramsFilter" and filter the result that corresponds to all selected tags
for example: 
   if "paramsFilter" = ["Apple", "Microsoft"] the result expected is = [] for not matching all selected tags

Thank you all
````

Comment: not too clear, why { "name": "Item-A", "tags": ["Facebook", "Google"] } doesnt appear in the expected result ????

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried so far to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your filterarray is used by at least one (i.e. OR) you could make it like this:

Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter for your desire and [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for getting all objects with at least one hit.
If you want instead all filter than use instead [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
myArray = [
  {
    "name": "Item-A", "tags":
    ["Facebook", "Google"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Item-B", "tags":
    ["Facebook", "Google", "Apple"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Item-C", "tags":
    ["Apple"]
  },
    {
    "name": "Item-D", "tags":
    ["Dell"]
  },
];

paramsFilter = ["Facebook", "Apple"];

let res = myArray.filter(({tags}) => tags.some(tag => paramsFilter.includes(tag)));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I was just going to give him this exact same answer. lol

Comment: @André von Kugland - If you are using short code than there are not so much possibilities ;)

Comment: thank you very much, this is very close to what I need, I edited my post on the result to match all the values of "paramsFilter"

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your array like this:

```
    myArray.filter((value) => value.tags.join("")!== paramsFilter.join(""))
```

Comment: and save this in a variable. Don't forget to upvote. If this works. Thanks

Comment: This assumes all params match. I think he wanted "any one of them".

Comment: I won't understand. Then why you have not selected ITEM A. Can you clarify on that

Comment: I think the question is poorly asked. Nevertheless the problem with searching arrays by string concatenation remains. Don't search arrays that way unless you are certain of a very specific usage (and even then it's not a good idea, no need for it).

Comment: Adding a quick explanation with this code sample can help improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think question has some issue, but if i understand the question ignoring the part where it is wrong, following snippet should work.

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    "name": "Item-A", "tags":
      ["Facebook", "Google"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Item-B", "tags":
      ["Facebook", "Google", "Apple"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Item-C", "tags":
      ["Apple"]
  },
];

function filterArray(params) {
   return myArray.filter(i => i.tags.filter((n) => params.indexOf(n) > -1).length > 0);
}

console.log(filterArray(['Apple']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all the tips and support, based on the examples I managed to solve with the following code:

`myArray.filter(item => paramsFilter.every(tag => item.tags.some(option => option === tag)))`